# Unexpected token al intentar escribir con Javascript en el innerHTML un código recibido por PHP

Tags: javascript, php7, iframe, innerhtml

Tengo un formulario para insertar y actualizar productos. Para actualizar, recibo los datos de la base de datos en la misma página que está incluyendo dicho formulario. Es un objeto y he comprobado que lo recibo perfectamente. En el formulario tengo un iframe  editable que uso para editar texto WYSIWYG. Al insertar producto logro guardarlo (el innerHTML del iframe editable) bien en la base de datos con el resto de campos.

Pero a la hora de insertar el valor quiero que muestre en dicho iframe el valor que tenía guardado en la base de datos, si lo escribo sin comillas...

```
<?php if($miProducto->getId() > 0): ?>
        <script>
            var micte = document.getElementById('CampoDeTextoEnriquecido');
            micte.document.body.innerHTML =<?php echo $miProducto->getDescripcionLarga() ?>;
        </script>
<?php endif ?>
```

El error es el que menciono en el título: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'**.

Si lo escribo con comillas dobles...

```
<?php if($miProducto->getId() > 0): ?>
    <script>
        var micte = document.getElementById('CampoDeTextoEnriquecido');
        micte.document.body.innerHTML ="<?php echo $miProducto->getDescripcionLarga() ?>";
    </script>
<?php endif ?>
```

El error es: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number**.

Y, finalmente, si lo  pongo con comillas simples:

```
<?php if($miProducto->getId() > 0): ?>
        <script>
            var micte = document.getElementById('CampoDeTextoEnriquecido');
            micte.document.body.innerHTML ='<?php echo $miProducto->getDescripcionLarga() ?>';
        </script>
<?php endif ?>
```

El error es **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of null**.

Como digo el  contenido son etiquetas html generadas por el editor WYSIWYG  creado en  JavasCript y que funciona. Por ejemplo, el texto de ese campo de uno de los productos es:

```
<h1><font size="7"><font color="#bede0c" style="background-color: rgb(250, 35, 12);">Probando</font> la descripción larga del producto.</font></h1>
```

¿Alguien puede decirme qué otra forma hay de mostrarlo? Aclaro que en cualquier otra parte de la página,  por ejemplo en un

o sin nada se muestra perfectamente tal cuál lo edité.
¡Un saludo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabo de encontrar **la solución** en una página externa. No la incluyo porque no sé si sólo  se pueden enlazar de unas páginas concretas o no.
El caso es que me ha funcionado.

Finalmente lo he solucionado de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php if($miProducto->getId() > 0): ?>
    <script>
        var micte = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow;
        micte.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = '<?php echo $miProducto->getDescripcionLarga() ?>';
    </script>
<?php endif ?>
```

Ahora SÍ me lo muestra, dentro del iframe, tal cuál lo edite.
Espero que a alguien pueda servirle de ayuda también.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if($miProducto->getId() > 0): ?>
        <script>
            var micte = document.getElementById('CampoDeTextoEnriquecido');
            micte.document.body.innerHTML =<?php echo $miProducto->getDescripcionLarga() ?>;
        </script>
<?php endif ?>
```

No puedes ejecutar php dentro de javascript de manera directa, pero si puedes hacerlo a la inversa, ahora bien, si lo haces de la otra forma que propones:

```
<?php if($miProducto->getId() > 0): ?>
        <script>
            var micte = document.getElementById('CampoDeTextoEnriquecido');
            micte.document.body.innerHTML ='<?php echo $miProducto->getDescripcionLarga() ?>';
        </script>
<?php endif ?>
```

No estas ejecutando php de manera directa, por que el string esta siendo primero parseado, sin embargo, me queda la siguiente duda:

```
micte.document.body.innerHTML
```

?????

Creo que te referias mas bien a esto:

```
var micte = document.getElementById('CampoDeTextoEnriquecido');
micte.innerHTML ='<?php echo $miProducto->getDescripcionLarga() ?>';
```

Sin embargo no se si se puede ejecutar php con comillas simples, intenta con las dobles y las simples por si acaso:

```
var micte = document.getElementById('CampoDeTextoEnriquecido');
micte.innerHTML ="<?php echo $miProducto->getDescripcionLarga() ?>";
```

Ahora bien, si quieres es añadirlo al final del `body` del documento debes hacer esto:

```
document.body.innerHTML += "<?php echo $miProducto->getDescripcionLarga() ?>";
```

Fijate en el `+=` es muy importante, ese operador le esta diciendo que a la propiedad innerHTML que debe usar lo que ya contiene y añadirle el contenido que le quieres dar, de lo contrario si solo pusieras `=` estarías reseteando todo el contenido que haya en el body y poniendole tu contenido.

Comment: El unexpected token se da porque javascript interpreta el contenido que le estas dando, pero PHP no lo esta procesando, es decir, es como si en un script cualquiera pusieras cosas que no sean de javascript.

Comment: Lo  de `micte.document.body.innerHTML` lo uso así porque es como aprendí a guardar  el contenido con el iframe en el textarea oculto como puedes ver aquí: `function submit_form() {
   document.getElementById('DescripcionLarga').value = cte.document.body.innerHTML;
   document.<?php echo $nombre_formulario ?>.submit();
  }` y creía que basándome en eso, podría hacerlo en  este caso para poner en el innerHTML del iframe lo obtenido de la base de datos.

Comment: Osea... ese elemento es como tal un iframe o no? porque si no es un iframe entonces micte.document.body.innerHTML es incorrecto y dará error.

Comment: Sí, es  un iframe. Pero he probado la solución que mencionas y sigue sin  funcionarme... El fragmento completo es:

Comment: `<textarea id="DescripcionLarga" name="DescripcionLarga" rows="25" cols="100" required><?php if($miProducto->getId() > 0): ?><?php echo $miProducto->getDescripcionLarga() ?><?php endif ?></textarea>
    <iframe name="campoDeTextoEnriquecido" id="campoDeTextoEnriquecido" style="border: #000000 5px solid; width: 850px; height: 500px;" ></iframe>
<?php if($miProducto->getId() > 0): ?>
     <script>
      var micte = document.getElementById('CampoDeTextoEnriquecido');
      micte.document.body.innerHTML +="<?php echo $miProducto->getDescripcionLarga() ?>";
     </script>
<?php endif ?>`

Comment: He probado tanto con `micte.document.body.innerHTML` como directamente `micte.innerHTML`. Y en ambos casos con y sin `+=`.. Concomillas dbles  me dice unexpected identifier... pero no me dice qué idenfiticador es el inesperado...  y con comilla  simple, Cannot read property 'document' of null...

Comment: Entonces mis sospechas son ciertas, no puedes ejecutar php dentro de javascript, php no lo renderizara.

Comment: Ok, muchas  gracias. Tendré que buscar otra  forma... si se te ocurre alguna... Pero eso me deja la duda de por qué  `function submit_form() { document.getElementById('DescripcionLarga').value = cte.document.body.innerHTML; document.<?php echo $nombre_formulario ?>.submit(); }` sí me funciona (se envía el formulario cuyo nombre está escrito en esa variable de PHP.)

Comment: Oye se me ocurre algo, en una de las partes del código que mostrarste, el de las comillas dobles, te apareció: unexpected number, que tal si en vez de usar innerHTML usas innerText y compruebas que hay? depronto no te lo pone porque tienes contenido html que esta fallando al ser renderizado?

Comment: Acabo de probarlo y el error que me da es unexpected identifier... No hayforma  dedar con la clave...  Probé también con scape y me fallaba también. Tengo que aclarar que los errores que menciono sólo me los muestra en la consola, no escritos en la página. En la página simplemente se muestra en blanco la  "caja" que es el iframe... y al darle al inspector veo esos  errores...

Comment: También he probado  a crear  un `echo` que escriba todo  el  script, con  concatenaciones para la  variable... pero ni por esas. Los errores siguen siendo iguales... Supongo que debe ser por incluir los caracteres de etiquetas html... Lo único que  se me  ocurre es guardarlos en la base de datos  sustituyendo comillas simples, comillas  dobles, <  y >  y cualquier otro  caracter  especial por sus códigos unicode o  algo así.. y al  recuperarlos, volverlos a  transformar una vez en  el  innerHTML para que  se muestre visualmente... Pero tampoco sé cómo hacerlo... :D